# how to send form data of array from angular to php script

Tags: php, angular, multipartform-data, form-data

I am not able to send an array list to the PHP script to get list of data.

Below is my angular service.

```
sendFormData(userData) {
console.log('hi');
console.log(userData);
var data = [];
data.push(userData);
console.log(data); 

return this.http.post("http://localhost:8088/post_candidateDetails.php", data);

}
```

PHP script

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Custom-Header, Origin, Content-Type , Authorisation , X-Requested-With");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 ");
print_r($_REQUEST);

?>
```

I am get blank output array in my browser.

```
Array
(
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of sending form data in Angular, $http POST data information is serialized as `application/json` which is not interpretable by `PHP`.

You have to transform the request (the form data object) into a format that it understands. The easiest way is to configure the $httpProvider.

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', '$httpParamSerializerProvider', function($http, $httpParamSerializerProvider) {
    var paramSerializer = $httpParamSerializerProvider.$get();
    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
    $http.defaults.transformRequest = function(data) {
        return paramSerializer(data);
    };
}]);
```

[taken from here](https://ericjam.com/2017/03/sending-angular-http-post-data-to-php/)

[a details example](https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/angular-php-app-creating-new-item-with-httpclient-post)

Comment: I am using Angus new version 8 can update full answer i am using this url:http://localhost:8088/post_candidateDetails.php. @Frost

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan this is nothing to do with angular - your angular is sending data but php can't receive it. update your php data receive function

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan if you need to understand something in details, this might help you
https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/angular-php-app-creating-new-item-with-httpclient-post

Comment: where i have to add this url:http://localhost:8088/post_candidateDetails.php in your  above  answer code , i m very new to angular.@Frost

Comment: Your answer is not helped me.@Frost

Comment: I am sorry, I am new too :) @mohdmazharkhan

Comment: but where i have to paste your code in my angular project tell me atleaset that.@Frost

Comment: In detail example your code answer code not there. @Frost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219444/discussion-between-mohd-mazhar-khan-and-frost).